# Sony Smart TV screen saver app

Tags: google-tv, sony

Is there a way an app can be written for Sony Google TV screen saver? I.e., can an Android app take over the screen saver mode of the TV?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is currently not possible for a 3rd party app to take over the screen saver mode on Google TV.